# Module support in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Modules in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596147/modules-in-c0x)
>   [why a compiler can't find a template definition in .cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620494/why-a-compiler-cant-find-a-template-definition-in-cpp)

I'm wondering if it is planned to add a Module support in C++ instead of current header system ?

I have discovered this paper : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2316.pdf

Any news on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Modules aren't in the new C++0X/C++11.

See: [C++ Modules - why were they removed from C++0x? Will they be back later on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596147/modules-in-c0x)