# Header files and modules in C++: friends or enemies?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, header-files, c++-modules

There is a [Working Draft, Extensions to C++ for Modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4681.pdf) (found in [Experimental C++ Features](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental)). If this becomes Standard, what will it mean for traditional headers?

I mean, when I hear about importing a module, I think about Angular or Python, where I exclusively import things, not include them.

Does that mean that the module system will replace includes? Or they will play along, and be used where they are suited best?

---

Material like [Include specific function from a header file into the code in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974642/include-specific-function-from-a-header-file-into-the-code-in-c) present it that way.

Comment: That's the intent. Gabriel Dos Reis gave a talk at CppCon2015 with a motivating example. The code the programmer sees will likely be the same order of size (in terms of LOC). But the code the *compiler* will have to see and go through, will be hundreds of % shorter. This should affect build time.

Comment: That's what I thought about too @StoryTeller when I heard about it. However, I think it would be a good idea to ask the question, in order to get something more formal, and more information! (Thanks for the edit)

Comment: @StoryTeller hundres of %? one hundred % shorter is still too much?

Comment: @tobi303 - Work in reverse :P An inclusion bloats the translation unit by hundreds of %. So my intent was that the bloat is reduced by about the same order of magnitude (in theory).

Comment: And yes. I hope the intent is to get rid of the preprocessor almost entirely. Leaving it with it's singular unique use, as a token concatenation mechanism.

Comment: I'd still need to include for some macros. For example, I have a macro that use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` for logging purposes. I think including it make it much more clearer than having macro exported, because it's clear you have preprocessor semantics.