# is there g++ 7.2 option to emit a message when it is using a precompiled header file?

Tags: c++, g++, precompiled-headers

I know about the '-H' option but that is way too verbose  when the precompiled header is NOT used.  What I want is the the output -H gives when it DOES use a preocompiled header.

I suspect the answer is "no" but I thought I'd throw a hail mary and ask here.

Comment: Why do you ask? precompiled headers are just some "cache" of headers!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [GCC option summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary). Then read about the GCC [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html). Read also about [precompiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) (conceptually, it is just some cache). They have limitations that I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108).

Why can't you use `-H` and filter, perhaps by some script using `grep` or `awk`, its output? You could also use some `-M*` option.

Otherwise, you might write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). It would use the `PLUGIN_INCLUDE_FILE` event.

My opinion is that writing a plugin for just that information is overkill.

At last, GCC is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You are allowed to [get](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) its source code and improve it (I am not sure it is worth the effort to understand the [internals of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/) for just your purposes). You probably should publish your improvements under GPLv3+ (but that is an ethical or legal or open source licensing question, so off-topic here; be aware of the [GCC runtime library exception](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception-3.1.en.html)). You could pay some GCC expert to do the work for you.

Future C++20 (or later) *might* have [modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4637.pdf) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621565/841108) and read [p1103r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1103r0.pdf)). Of course, you'll need a more recent GCC than the old [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/). You could need to wait for GCC 10 or later.

Maybe you should look at other languages, e.g. [Rust](https://rust-lang.org/), [Go](https://golang.org/), or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/).